# How to not cancel touch drag event inside ListView item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm implementing a swipe gesture similar to the one in Android Gmail app where you drag across an item to archive it.

I attach a touch listener to the item view and a gesture detector and listener to listen to touch events like this:

```
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gl;
gl = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float dx, float dy) {
        // ... handle horizontal scrolling
        return true;
    }
};
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(getContext(), gl);
itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        gd.onTouchEvent(e);
        // ... handle TOUCH_UP and TOUCH_CANCEL
        return true;
    }
});
```

The problem is that as soon as I start dragging vertically, or go outside the bounds of the item view, the gesture is cancelled and list view starts handling it for normal vertical list scrolling. I need the gesture to not cancel until the user releases the finger, even if it moves outside the table cell, like it's done in Gmail app.

How do I have it not cancelled?

Comment: maybe that could help: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss